# Existence of Minimum Value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Assume $x\ge0$, show that the function $f(x,y)=(2xy+y^2)e^{-x}$ has a minimum value. Note that actual minimum value is $-4e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$f(x,y)=(x+y)^2 e^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}.$$
The first term is $\ge 0$. The second term is a function of $1$ variable, which is easy to analyze. For example, we can express it as $\dfrac{x^2}{e^x}$, and use the fact that $e^x\gt \dfrac{x^2}{2!}$.

Comment: Thank you! I am grateful for your incredibly speedy response.

Comment: You are welcome. It was quick because the "completing the square" strategy was so clearly useful.